# Matching an exact key in SwiftyJson

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I'm really having trouble with determining a specific value returned in SwiftyJson; hopefully, someone can help explain this to me.

I want to see if there is a match between a predetermined word, "apple" to any of the words received from the JSON responses.

If there is a match then a message is displayed, and the user either chooses to progress to the next level or the user returns to the home screen.

If there is no match then a message is displayed, and the user must either continue playing or cancel playing.

I would like to do this for multiple words across different levels of the game.

Level one: match "apple" to any of the received JSON responses.

Level two: match "computer" to any of the received JSON responses.

Level three: match "telephone" or "phone" or "iPhone" or "Android" or any or all of the above to any of the received JSON responses.

So, basically, I can get all of the JSON responses, but I'm having a hard time finding out how to set up to determine if there is a specific, predefined JSON response returned.

I have looked everywhere for weeks with another post but to no avail :(

**JSON RESPONSES**

```
    {
  "responses" : [
    {
      "labelAnnotations" : [
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/01m2v",
          "score" : 0.9245476,
          "description" : "computer keyboard"
        },
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/01c648",
          "score" : 0.7945268,
          "description" : "laptop"
        },
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/01mfj",
          "score" : 0.74227184,
          "description" : "computer hardware"
        },
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/0541p",
          "score" : 0.7062791,
          "description" : "multimedia"
        },
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/07c1v",
          "score" : 0.7039645,
          "description" : "technology"
        },
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/03gq5hm",
          "score" : 0.69323385,
          "description" : "font"
        },
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/0bs7_0t",
          "score" : 0.6724673,
          "description" : "electronic device"
        },
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/01vdm0",
          "score" : 0.66489816,
          "description" : "electronic keyboard"
        },
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/0121tl",
          "score" : 0.60392517,
          "description" : "electronic instrument"
        },
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/0h8n5_7",
          "score" : 0.5834592,
          "description" : "laptop replacement keyboard"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**CODE TO SHOW ALL JSON RESPONSES**

```
 // Use SwiftyJSON to parse results
        let json = JSON(data: dataToParse)
        let errorObj: JSON = json["error"]

 // Parse the response
            print(json)
            let responses: JSON = json["responses"][0]

                // Get label annotations
            let labelAnnotations: JSON = responses["labelAnnotations"]
            let numLabels: Int = labelAnnotations.count
            var labels: Array<String> = []
            if numLabels > 0 {
                var labelResultsText:String = "Labels found: "
                for index in 0..<numLabels {
                    let label = labelAnnotations[index]["description"].stringValue
                    labels.append(label)
                }
                for label in labels {
                    // if it's not the last item add a comma
                    if labels[labels.count - 1] != label {
                        labelResultsText += "\(label), "
                    } else {
                        labelResultsText += "\(label)"
                    }
                }
                self.labelResults.text = labelResultsText
            } else {
                self.labelResults.text = "No labels found"
            }
```

***EDIT***

I'm apparently not able to answer my own question, I'll post an edit since I think it's a better solution but @pierce's was pretty decent for a single word, not many; it just wasn't applicable for a game setting application.

So, I created a new NSObject, created a

`static var _words: [[String]] = [`

```
["apple", "computer", "beer"]]
```

then

```
func checkAnnotations(annotations: [Annotation]) -> Bool {
    var isMatched = false

    let searchWords = self.words
    for searchWord in searchWords {
        for annotation in annotations {
            if searchWord == annotation.descriptionString {
                isMatched = true
                break
            }
        }

        if isMatched {
            break
        }
    }

    return isMatched
}
```

then created a function to handle the level state,

and finally compared that to the JSON response in the View Controller and advanced level if matched

```
            // Get JSON key value
            let labelAnnotations = responses["labelAnnotations"].arrayValue
            let annotationObjects: [Annotation] = labelAnnotations.flatMap({ annotationDictionary in
                if let mid = annotationDictionary["mid"].string,
                let score = annotationDictionary["score"].double,
                    let description = annotationDictionary["description"].string {
                    let annotation = Annotation(mid: mid, score: score, descriptionString: description)
                    return annotation
                }

                return nil
            })

            //print(annotationObjects)

            let searchString = LevelState.shared.words[0]
            print("Level \(LevelState.shared.level), looking for: \(searchString)")

            var isMatched = LevelState.shared.checkAnnotations(annotations: annotationObjects)
            if isMatched {
                LevelState.shared.advance()
            }

            let alertTitle = isMatched ? "Congrats! You got \(searchString)" : "Keep looking for \(searchString)"

            //let translationResult = "Translated: \(levelDescription) to \(translatedText)"

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

        self.prepareForNewLevel()
        })
    }
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear about a couple things: First - why are you adding a comma to every entry of your `labels` array? Second it looks like you setup `labels` to be each `description` from your `JSON`...so if you need to compare those values to some word the user inputs, would filter work for you? `let matches = labels.filter { $0.contains(user_entered_word) }`

Comment: the commas are only used if there is more than one JSON response returned; that clearly won't be necessary to have if I am predefining a single desired word. if i can use "filter" then sure, as I have seen in other examples, but i'm not sure how to set that up in my code :/ One minute I feel like I really understand Json, the next minute I'm totally confused by parsing it. @Pierce

Comment: I added an answer below for you. Hope it helps

Comment: Was there a problem with my answer? Why did you unaccept it? I'm just curious

Comment: read the edit in my post above. it's not bad but I think my solution is a little more comprehensive. I can't post an answer @Pierce

Answer (score 0):

First thing - I really don't understand why you want to append a comma at the end of each description. I really thing that's unnecessary. Are you confused about separating elements in an array? Because the actual `String`s don't require that, it's only if you're manually writing out the elements of an array (i.e. `let array = ["a", "b", "c"]`).

So then say you setup a property for this `labels` array, which is an array of `String`s.

```
var labels: Array<String> = []
```

Once you've gone through and appended all the `description` values from your `JSON`, you can then manipulate it.

```
if numLabels > 0 {

    for index in 0..<numLabels {
        let label = labelAnnotations[index]["description"].stringValue
        labels.append(label)
    }

}
```

Now you could create a method that would return a filtered array of `String`s based on some user entered word:

```
func findMatches(_ userEntry: String) -> [String] {

    return labels.filter { $0.contains(userEntry) }

}
```

Now you could use the above method to handle some sort of user entry, like say you had the text from a `UITextField` named `textField`:

```
// Return the filtered matches based on the textField text (unless nil)
let matches = findMatches(textField.text ?? "")

// Print the number of matches, and also show the matches
print("Found \(matches.count) matches to user input\r\(matches)")
```

Now if you had `labels` which held `["a", "aa", "ba", "b", "c", "apple"]`, and ran the above code where the `userEntry` was just the letter "a", you'd see this print out in the console window:

```
Found 4 matches to user input
["a", "aa", "ba", "apple"]
```

EDIT - You can use the `findMatches` method above for what you're trying to do with pre-determined words to match. I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but there are a couple different ways. First, say you had an array of pre-determined words you wanted to check as an array:

```
let words = ["word", "verb", "noun", "adverb"]
```

Then you could loop through that and check each one

```
for word in words {

    let matches = findMatches(word)
    if matches.count > 0 {
        print("Found \(matches.count) matches to \(word)\r\(matches)")
    } else {
        // Do whatever you want when there are no matches
        print("No matches found")
    }

}
```

If you want to just check for a specific word, and have a specific response you could setup a method like so:

```
func checkWord(word: String, noMatchResponse: String) {

    let matches = findMatches(word)
    if matches.count > 0 {
        print("Found \(matches.count) matches to \(word)\r\(matches)")
    } else {
        // Do whatever with the no match response
        print(noMatchResponse)
    }

}
```

There are so many ways you could implement this. You could also use a `switch` statement, and then use different `case` statements for each pre-determined word. It's really up to you and how you want to design your game.

Comment: @pythlang - Oh okay I see what you're saying. To keep things working right, I would only recommend doing something like that right when you're planning to print.

Comment: brilliant, I'll try this out.  Adding a comma to the end of each description works for me because I just have the results returned in a long sentence like this: "Labels found: stem, table, hand, apple", so if I were to omit the appended commas the list would look pretty bad i.e.: "Labels found: stem table hand apple". If appending with the comma is superfluous and will be done anyway by ".count" then I guess I could always remove it. There will be no user-entry, rather these predefined words will be hard-coded by myself in terms of how the game should progress. How would that look? @Pierce

Comment: @pythlang - It would look exactly the same, you could just substitute your predefined word for the part where I used text from a textField: `let matches = findMatches("your_predefined_word")`

Comment: thank you, I'll test this out shortly and if there are any problems I'll post back; if not, I'll accept your answer. Thanks again. @Pierce

Comment: I'm getting a "use of unresolved identifiers 'labels'" when running `let matches = findMatches("your_predefined_word")` under the `func findMatches` @Pierce

Comment: in any case, your answer is helpful, but turning out to be incomplete for my needs. I need to be able to print a second message if the response was not matched and be able to use multiple "filters" without creating new functions every time; think of it like a matching game where one would use "switch" and "case". this is really stumping me hard. @Pierce

Comment: @pythlang - you need to declare the `labels` array at the beginning of your class like I said above. You can use the code I gave you to do exactly what you're proposing, you just have to customize it a little bit

Comment: wow.... I totally left it out and accidentally put it in another view controller. If you're saying I can do that, then I'll give it a go... Thank you so much, I will accept your answer. @Pierce

Comment: @pythlang - Sure thing. Check back in a minute. I will try and edit my answer for what I think you're going for

Comment: @pythlang - check my updated answer. I think it will help lead you in the right direction.

Comment: wow, thank you, that is much easier for me to understand when written out like that. You've helped beyond measure.

Comment: @pythlang - Don't mention it. Good luck with your game!